# Updating selection of server-side selectize input with >1000 choices fails

Tags: r, shiny, selectize.js

I have a shiny app containing a server-side selectize input with a long list (>10k) of choices.
I would like to update the selection upon clicking a button. Here is a reproducible example

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton('buttonid','Button'),

  selectizeInput("listid", "A long list", choices = NULL)
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) 
  {
  updateSelectizeInput(session, "listid", choices = paste("Item", 1:10000), server = T)
  observeEvent(input$buttonid,
               {
               updateSelectizeInput(session, "listid", selected = "Item 1234")
               })
  }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The above code results in a blank selection when I press the button.
However, if I search for "Item 1234", then change selection, and press the button, now the item gets selected.

Also, trying to select an item between Item 1 and 1000 does not give problems, presumably because 1000 items get loaded at the beginning.

This seems akin to this old bug, but I am not sure if there is a workaround https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1018

Comment: I also sent this as a bug report https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2760

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is explicitly re-specify your `choices` and `server` in your update.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) 
{

  myChoices <- paste("Item", 1:10000)

  updateSelectizeInput(session, "listid", choices = myChoices, server = T)
  observeEvent(input$buttonid,
               {
                 updateSelectizeInput(session, "listid",
                                      server = TRUE,
                                      choices = myChoices,
                                      selected = "Item 1234")

               })
}
```

The default for `server` in `updateSelectizeInput` is `FALSE`. This causes the code to drop into a control statement which uses `updateSelectInput` instead. From the function code

```
function (session, inputId, label = NULL, choices = NULL, selected = NULL, 
    options = list(), server = FALSE) 
{
    ...

    if (!server) {
        return(updateSelectInput(session, inputId, label, choices, 
            selected))
    }

   ...
```

This sends a message to the client assuming all the choices are present (but as you mentioned, only the first 1000 are present).

Just setting `server = TRUE` results in an error when you click the button.

```
Warning: Error in [.data.frame: undefined columns selected
  [No stack trace available]
```

I didn't fully trace the reason, but it ultimately creates an empty choices data.frame with an attribute denoting the selected value. I'm guessing somewhere else in function calls to the `session` object, this attribute is being used to try to select a column created from the empty data.frame.

The update function doesn't seem to change the `choices` stored on the server, so that's presumably why it's there when you search for it. During the changing the selected value, it seems to be trying to select from a NULL list of choices instead of the list of choices on the server.

It seems like you essentially have to recreate your `selectizeInput` when updating with a selected value beyond your initial list.

Answer (score 5):

You can use maxOptions to render all values, might be enough depending on the size of your choices:

```
selectizeInput("listid", "A long list", choices = NULL, options = list(maxOptions = 10000))
```

Comment: Thank you Clemsang, I think the other solution works better in my particular case, but this is a good option nevertheless.

Comment: Totally agree. It might be usefull for the community in the future to have this simple workaround.