# Shiny doesn't show me the entire selectInput when I have choices > 1000

Tags: r, shiny

I have written a simple example of what I am doing. I have 3000 numbers that I want to show in a selectInput. The numbers have to be in a reactive function, since in my original work, the data is from a file.

My problem is that when I run the app it only appears 1000 numbers, not the entire data (3000 numbers).

I have seen this post [Updating selection of server-side selectize input with >1000 choices fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60264119/updating-selection-of-server-side-selectize-input-with-1000-choices-fails) but I don't know how can I do it using uiOutput and renderUI.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks very much in advance

The code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Numbers"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput('selectUI')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  num <- reactive({
    data = c(1:3000)
    return(data)
  })
  
  output$selectUI <- renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId = 'options', "Select one", choices = num())  
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `selectizeInput` instead of `selectInput` with the argument `options = list(maxOptions = 3000)`.

Comment: Thanks very much. It works, but it gives me this warning.
`Warning: The select input "options" contains a large number of options; consider using server-side selectize for massively improved performance. See the Details section of the ?selectizeInput help topic.`

Could it be fixed or it doesn't matter?

Comment: This could be solved writing server=TRUE

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Stéphane Laurent's answer, the example will be solved like this:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Numbers"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput(inputId = "options", label = "Select one", choices=character(0)),
      
    ),
    mainPanel(
      
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  num <- reactive({
    data = c(1:3000)
    return(data)
  })
  
 
  observe({
  updateSelectizeInput(
      session = session,
      inputId = "options",
      label = "Select one",
      choices= num(), options=list(maxOptions = length(num())),
      server = TRUE)
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This code will work if you have more than 3000 entries. It will show you ALL the choices that you have. However, if you have a long list of choices (e.g. 60000) it will decrease the speed of your app.