# Reactive ggplot with Shiny-

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

**Hi community**
Im try to make a reactive Shiny app.

When I select the name "Lugar" appear the plot. Im have the code of the each plot that in need but dont run well in shiny.

```
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  precip = read_excel("meses2.xlsx", sheet="F")
  #Summarize Data and then Plot
  data <- reactive({
    req(input$sel_Lugar)
    df <- precip %>% filter(Lugar %in% input$sel_Lugar) %>%  group_by(Mes) %>% summarise(precip = sum(Medicion))
  })
  
  #Update SelectInput Dynamically
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "sel_Lugar", choices = precip$Lugar)
  })
  
  #Plot 
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data(),aes(x=sel_Lugar, y=Medicion, fill=Mes,na.rm = TRUE)) +
      geom_col() +
      scale_fill_manual(values=c("#E23D2C","#BAA512","#512B9A","#21AB3F")) + 
      labs(title = "Distribución general de la precipitación",
           caption= "Fuente: propia")+
      ylab("Precipitación (mm)") +
      theme_light()
    
  })
}

ui <- basicPage(
  h1("R Shiny Dynamically create Drop Down List"),
  selectInput(inputId = "sel_Lugar",
              label = "Choose Sales Rep",
              "Names"),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

-

Im need that in one sheet appear this not reactive plot

In other sheet/tabs Im need put the reactive plot. This is the code. Im want that when select the "lugar" appear the plot. Are 4 "Lugar"

```
d_New<-read_excel("meses2.xlsx", sheet="F")

ggplot(d_New, aes(x=Lugar, y=Medicion, fill=Mes,na.rm = TRUE)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#E23D2C","#BAA512","#512B9A","#21AB3F")) + 
  labs(title = "Distribución general de la precipitación",
       caption= "Fuente: propia")+
  ylab("Precipitación (mm)") +
  theme_light()
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

The app run and show this.
[image]

**Example data**

```
structure(list(Mes = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo"), class = "factor"), 
    Dia = c(17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 
    17, 18, 19, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 17, 18, 19, 
    20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 
    23, 24, 25, 26, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15), Medicion = c(50, 
    17, 13, 12, 3, 6, 0.3, NA, 13, 1, 4, 20, 3, NA, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 20, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 0, 0, 5, 9, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 17, 58, 32, 0, 9, 0.5, 1, 25, 1, 0.5, 
    4, 10, 3, 3, 8, 36, 13, 1, 0.5, 0.5), Lugar = c("UNIAGRARIA", 
    "UNIAGRARIA", "UNIAGRARIA", "UNIAGRARIA", "UNIAGRARIA", "UNIAGRARIA", 
    "UNIAGRARIA", "UNIAGRARIA", "UNIAGRARIA", "UNIAGRARIA", "UNIAGRARIA", 
    "UNIAGRARIA", "UNIAGRARIA", "GRANADA NORTE", "GRANADA NORTE", 
    "GRANADA NORTE", "GRANADA NORTE", "GRANADA NORTE", "GRANADA NORTE", 
    "RIO FRIO", "RIO FRIO", "RIO FRIO", "RIO FRIO", "RIO FRIO", 
    "RIO FRIO", "RIO FRIO", "RIO FRIO", "CHICU", "CHICU", "CHICU", 
    "CHICU", "CHICU", "CHICU", "CHICU", "CHICU", "CHICU", "CHICU", 
    "CHICU", "RIO FRIO", "RIO FRIO", "RIO FRIO", "RIO FRIO", 
    "RIO FRIO", "RIO FRIO", "RIO FRIO", "RIO FRIO", "RIO FRIO", 
    "RIO FRIO", "RIO FRIO", "GRANADA NORTE", "GRANADA NORTE", 
    "GRANADA NORTE", "GRANADA NORTE", "GRANADA NORTE", "GRANADA NORTE", 
    "GRANADA NORTE", "GRANADA NORTE", "GRANADA NORTE", "GRANADA NORTE", 
    "GRANADA NORTE")), row.names = c(NA, -60L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**Thanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to have 2 tabs (1 for the fixed plot and 1 for the reactive plot) you need to use `navbarPage`.

"sel_Lugar" was not found and it couldn't be used for the plot because `data()` doesn't have this column. The way that you tried to get data it was giving you a column with "Mes" and another column with "precip".

[image: image 1]

I don't know why you were trying to `summarise`, but if you want to draw the plots, you need to remove this part.

[image]

Therefore, you will be able to use the columns "Lugar", "Medicion" and "Mes" in the plot.

On the other hand, the code that you were using to draw the reactive plot is wrong.

```
ggplot(precip, aes(x=Lugar, y=Medicion, fill=Mes,na.rm = TRUE)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#E23D2C","#BAA512","#512B9A","#21AB3F")) + 
  labs(title = "Distribución general de la precipitación",
       caption= "Fuente: propia")+
  ylab("Precipitación (mm)") +
  theme_light()
```

If you want to get the same output that you attached in the photos (for the reactive plot), you need to change the x (instead of "Lugar", it has to be "Dia"). Besides, if you want a scale that contains "Dias" I recommend you to use `scale_x_continuous`.
In my case, I have used `scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(from=0, to = max(precip$Dia), by=1))`

> seq(from=0, to = max(precip$Dia), by=1)
> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lD3uQ.png)  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 3

I have changed the way that you show the places (`selectInput`), since I have saved the choices into a function.
However, if for any case you have a huge list of options, I recommend you to use `selectizeInput`. Here you have one [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67058559/shiny-doesnt-show-me-the-entire-selectinput-when-i-have-choices-1000/72375609#72375609).

After all the changes that I made, this is how your app looks.

[image]
[image]

Here I attach you the entire code.

Note that I added a table where you can see how you are subsetting your data according to the `selectInput`.

```
library(shinythemes)
library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)

# Since you want to have 1 tab for the "not reactive plot" and another tab for the "reactive plot", you will need to use navbarPage
ui <-  fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("flatly"), # this is to put some colors/themes
  navbarPage(
    title = "R Shiny Dynamically create Drop Down List", 
    collapsible = TRUE,
    fluid = TRUE,
    
    tabPanel(
      title = "Not reactive plot", 
      
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel = sidebarPanel(
         
        ), 
        
        mainPanel = mainPanel(
          plotOutput("plot1")
        )
      )
    ),
    tabPanel(
      title = "Reactive plot", 
      
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel = sidebarPanel(
          uiOutput('selectUI'), # this is to have the list of places
        ), 
        
        mainPanel = mainPanel(
          plotOutput("plot2"),
          dataTableOutput("table")
        )
      )
    ),
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # this is your data without filtering
  data <- reactive({
    return(precip)
  })
  
  # this gives you the a vector of the choices of your original data
  lugar_choices <- reactive({
    choices <- levels(data()$Lugar)
    return(choices)
  })
  
  # this will give you your choices.
  output$selectUI <- renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId = 'sel_Lugar', "Choose Sales Rep", choices = lugar_choices())  
  })
  
  # this your new data according to your select Input.
  data_filtered <- reactive({
    req(input$sel_Lugar)
    df <-  data() %>%
      filter(Lugar %in% input$sel_Lugar) %>%
      group_by(Mes)
    return(df)
  })
  
  # first plot (not reactive)
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data(), aes(x=Lugar, y=Medicion, fill=Mes,na.rm = TRUE)) +
      
      geom_col() +
      scale_fill_manual(values=c("#E23D2C","#BAA512","#512B9A","#21AB3F")) + 
      labs(title = "Distribución general de la precipitación",
           caption= "Fuente: propia")+
      ylab("Precipitación (mm)") +
      theme_light()
  })
  
  # second plot (reactive)
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data_filtered(), aes(x=Dia, y=Medicion, fill=Mes,na.rm = TRUE)) +
      geom_col() +
      scale_fill_manual(values=c("#E23D2C","#BAA512","#512B9A","#21AB3F")) + 
      labs(title = "Distribución general de la precipitación",
           caption= "Fuente: propia")+
      ylab("Precipitación (mm)") +
      scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(from=0, to = max(data_filtered()$Dia), by=1))+
      theme_light()
  })
  
  # this is the info that you are plotting 
  output$table <- renderDataTable(data_filtered())
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Data:

```
precip = structure(list(Mes = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                          2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                          1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                                          2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                          3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo"), class = "factor"), 
                        Dia = c(17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 
                                17, 18, 19, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 17, 18, 19, 
                                20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 
                                23, 24, 25, 26, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15), Medicion = c(50, 
                                                                                                     17, 13, 12, 3, 6, 0.3, NA, 13, 1, 4, 20, 3, NA, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                     0, 20, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 0, 0, 5, 9, 
                                                                                                     0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 17, 58, 32, 0, 9, 0.5, 1, 25, 1, 0.5, 
                                                                                                     4, 10, 3, 3, 8, 36, 13, 1, 0.5, 0.5), Lugar = c("UNIAGRARIA", 
                                                                                                                                                     "UNIAGRARIA", "UNIAGRARIA", "UNIAGRARIA", "UNIAGRARIA", "UNIAGRARIA", 
                                                                                                                                                     "UNIAGRARIA", "UNIAGRARIA", "UNIAGRARIA", "UNIAGRARIA", "UNIAGRARIA", 
                                                                                                                                                     "UNIAGRARIA", "UNIAGRARIA", "GRANADA NORTE", "GRANADA NORTE", 
                                                                                                                                                     "GRANADA NORTE", "GRANADA NORTE", "GRANADA NORTE", "GRANADA NORTE", 
                                                                                                                                                     "RIO FRIO", "RIO FRIO", "RIO FRIO", "RIO FRIO", "RIO FRIO", 
                                                                                                                                                     "RIO FRIO", "RIO FRIO", "RIO FRIO", "CHICU", "CHICU", "CHICU", 
                                                                                                                                                     "CHICU", "CHICU", "CHICU", "CHICU", "CHICU", "CHICU", "CHICU", 
                                                                                                                                                     "CHICU", "RIO FRIO", "RIO FRIO", "RIO FRIO", "RIO FRIO", 
                                                                                                                                                     "RIO FRIO", "RIO FRIO", "RIO FRIO", "RIO FRIO", "RIO FRIO", 
                                                                                                                                                     "RIO FRIO", "RIO FRIO", "GRANADA NORTE", "GRANADA NORTE", 
                                                                                                                                                     "GRANADA NORTE", "GRANADA NORTE", "GRANADA NORTE", "GRANADA NORTE", 
                                                                                                                                                     "GRANADA NORTE", "GRANADA NORTE", "GRANADA NORTE", "GRANADA NORTE", 
                                                                                                                                                     "GRANADA NORTE")), row.names = c(NA, -60L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                           "tbl", "data.frame"))

# we transform the column into factors because we will need it for the choices (I will need the different levels)
precip$Lugar <- as.factor(precip$Lugar)
```

Comment: Tkns! @emr2, when Im run this code show this msm "Error in navbarPage(title = "R Shiny Dynamically create Drop Down List",  : 
  argumento ausente, sin argumento por omisión".

Im check but dont see the error.

Comment: Have you checked if you have all the packages in your system? Because I added some new. I have loaded the code and the data again and I don't receive that error, so I don't know why you have it.. Which version do you have of R? (Mine is 4.1.3). Have you tried to restart R too? Sometimes it works... (And finally, did you change the column "Lugar" to factor?) We need to figure it out if you have done all the changes to know what it is going on

Comment: Ok, yes, the code run well. Tnks!